# Selenium can't find locator

Tags: java, html, selenium

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I05M7.png)I have a list of checkboxes which can be scrollable, but I can't find the actual locator. This is the HTML:

```
<a class="collection-item" href="#!" disabled="">
  <span>
    <input id="3" class="filled-in checkbox-orange" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="3"/>
  </span>
  <span for="3">  3 AM- 4 AM </span>
</a>
```

I have tryed this but it's not working:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.collection-item").id("3"));
// or
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='time']/a[3]")).click();
// or
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(we1).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command" exception, you are probably setting your element display or visibility property to hidden in one of your css classes. To fix it, do this.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('3').setAttribute('display', 'block')");
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('3').setAttribute('visibility', 'visible')");
// Finally, click your checkbox.
driver.findElement(By.id('3')).click();
```

Comment: Showing exception brother,same exception as you mentioned, "document.getElementById('3')" i put like this is it correct

Comment: Do you have any display:none or visibility:hidden in your css classes?

Comment: Yeah i have display: blocked and dispaly:none

Comment: Which elements have display:none?

Comment: <div id="create_schedule" style="display: block;">  with in this my collection is there

Comment: type="checkbox" is visibility:hidden  ,thanks for your time

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='3']")).click();                            This piece of code also helped me to click on checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

To put mark in checkbox you should use `<input>` element, not `<a>`! So try following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//input[@class="filled-in checkbox-orange"][@type="checkbox"]')).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.id('3')).click();
```

Comment: Hai andersson, i have tried both of your lines not working,showing exception as "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command"

Comment: Does target element present on page after page loaded or you should scroll down to see it?

Comment: Yes target element is present on page after reload.

Comment: If solution provided by Aurasphere is not working, then seems that you need to add some extra seconds (implicit/explicit wait time) to let page completely load